# Permission denied when loading FTP Logging provider

Tags: iis, ftp

I have written an FTP Logging provider for IIS/FTP 7.5, using C#.

It is registered and configured, but whenever the server tries to load the file it fails.

I see in the ETW log an access denied error when trying to load the extension.  (0x80070005)

This is on a Windows 7 box for development, using Visual Studio 2010.

How do I determine what permission(s) are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I know.  Bad form to answer my own question.

It turns out that at least part of the issue was that the bitness was wrong.  I'd compiled at 32 bit when the server was running 64 bit.  The server couldn't load the extension, but it had **nothing** to do with permissions.